# How do I have my layout for the following

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

[image: This is my desired layout.]

I've got a list of items. The big box on the left is my image. The two boxes are text boxes. I want the above text box to be ellipsized. Here's my current layout file.

MainLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the layout within each list item is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Logo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/textViews"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With this, if my detail in upper box is too big, it takes two lines before `...`, and the textView below is never shown.

If the text in upper box is small, then it looks fine. How to restrict the overflowing of upper box to the entire list element size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to add `android:singleLine="true"` to the upper box.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give them a weight and set height to match_parent.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>
```